# Trouble with scanf command in c ( cant find anywhere else in forums)

Tags: c

```
FILE *datapad;
char filename[20];
printf("please enter file \n");
scanf(" %s", &filename);
fflush(stdin);
printf("processing");
datapad = fopen(filename,"r");
```

So this above is code for a project I'm working on but when I compile the code and run it gets stuck at the scan f command and I can't figure out what is going wrong, I've tried the fflush command and I have the formatting right with the ampersand.

Comment: First, remove the `&`. It does not belong there. Also, you probably want a line break at the end of "processing".

Comment: @Dyz the space before `%s` is harmless. It filters out leading whitespace, but with `%s` that will happen anyway.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @WeatherVane You are right (on both :)

Comment: 1) What was the filename entered?  2) Change `scanf(" %s", &filename);` --> `scanf("%19s", filename);`

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output as text

Comment: "trouble with scanf" is practically a tautology.  scanf is not suitable for beginners.  Stop using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format for your `scanf()` is incorrect

```
main()
{
    char filename[20];
    printf("please enter file \n");
    scanf("%19s", filename);
    printf("processing %s...\n", filename);
}
```

output:

```
please enter file
/we/sd/xc
processing /we/sd/xc...
```

Answer (score 0):

you have filename as array of character , here you are passing incorrent filename with scanf function. you can pass array as an arguments in two ways :

1 ) filename : pass name of array as argument, it will point to first element of an array

2 ) &filename[i] : pass i'th element of an array, this is helpful in the cases you have to pass element other than first element as an argument:

following is the correct program :

```
FILE *datapad;
char filename[20];
printf("please enter file \n");
scanf(" %s",filename);
fflush(stdin);
printf("processing");
datapad = fopen(filename,"r");
```